# How do you resolve the following error: Error: Cannot find module '@openzeppelin/test-helpers' (when typing 'truffle test' in VSCode terminal)

Tags: visual-studio-code, module, blockchain, solidity

I am trying to create a blockchain project and as I type in the following: truffle test - in the VSCode IDE terminal, I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module '@openzeppelin/test-helpers'

I am trying to create a blockchain supply chain project using Solidity programming language in VSCode IDE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
truffle compile --all
truffle migrate --reset
```

and it solve